# Resample and interpolate Dataframe by specific values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to resample and interpolate my data (ca. n=2400; years 1990 - 2000; Season: December - July, Price values) based on an index (development stage), which increments from 0 until 2. The increment is daily and the final value (2) can be reached mostly in July, however sometimes even in May. However, I would like to monitor price values at specific (interpolated) development stages, i.e. `DEV_LIST = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]` every season.

Here is my code snippet:

```
In: df
Out:
            day     DEV   PRICE MONTH   YEAR    MONTH_YEAR
0    1990-11-15  0.1000 15.0000    11   1990      Nov 1990
1    1990-11-16  0.1864 16.0000    11   1990      Nov 1990
2    1990-11-17  0.1937 20.0000    11   1990      Nov 1990
3    1990-11-18  0.2621 24.0000    11   1990      Nov 1990
4    1990-11-19  0.2634 30.0000    11   1990      Nov 1990
...         ...     ... ...       ...    ...           ...
2396 2000-06-06 1.9405  9010.0000  06   2000      Jun 2000
2397 2000-06-07 1.9568  9015.0000  06   2000      Jun 2000
2398 2000-06-08 1.9736  9020.0000  06   2000      Jun 2000
2399 2000-06-09 1.9907  9023.0000  06   2000      Jun 2000
2400 2000-06-10    NaN        NaN  06   2000      Jun 2000
```

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
DEV_LIST = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
year_range_for_dev = range(1990, 2001)
DEV_year = pd.DataFrame({'DEV' : 
                         [DEV for DEV in DEV_LIST for year in year_range_for_dev ], 
                         'YEAR': 
                         [year for DEV in DEV_LIST for year in year_range_for_dev]})
df_2 = df[['DEV', 'PRICE']]
df_2 = df_2[~df_2['DEV'].isin(DEV_LIST)].set_index('DEV')
df_2_resampled = df_2.reindex(df_2 .index.union(
                              DEV_year['DEV'])).interpolate('values')
```

Probably continuing with `pandas.merge_asof` for putting back dates later. However, I am not able to pass this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
     DEV      PRICE 
1    0.0    12.0000
2    0.1000 15.0000
3    0.1864 16.0000
4    0.1937 20.0000
5    0.2500 24.0000
6    0.2621 30.0000
7    0.2634 32.0000
 ...    ...       ...      
2405 1.9405 9010.0000
2406 1.9568 9015.0000
2407 1.9736 9020.0000 
2408 1.9907 9023.0000
2409 2.0000 9025.0000
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is df_2 really the dataframe setup you want? The index clearly has duplicate values; which is what that error is saying (in a roundabout way)

Comment: @JonathanLeon So should I do it without an index? But how? Of course, there will be sometimes duplicates, either that software will hit directly some number from list or NaN...

Comment: what is the expected outcome? if you post what you want the resulting dataframe to be, it'd be easier to help. also, this is in your code DVS_LIST, and never mentioned anywhere. typo?

Comment: @JonathanLeon I provided desired output... I am not sure if it is possible to do it with dates, so I do it without dates. Probably through pandas.merge_asof it would be possible. I hope that it is understandable... Values from DEV_LIST are now in dataframe with interpolated values...